# Сортировка данных в алфавитном порядке. С++

Tags: c++, сортировка

Вечер добрый. Нужна помощь с кодом. Если коротко, то программа должна выдавать статистику использования букв из текста в файле f.txt (текст любой) и выводить это в файл f1.txt. Все готово, все работает, за исключением того, что не могу написать код который бы позволял сортировать буквы в файле f1.txt  в алфавитном порядке. Функция, где я пыталась это сделать с названием DataSort. Спасибо.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void CreateArray(int data [62][2]) 
{
    for (int i=36; i<62;  i++) data[i][1]=i+61;
    for (int i=0; i<62;  i++) data[i][0]=0;
}

void ReadData(int data [62][2]) 
{
    ifstream f;
    f.open("f.txt");
    char c;
    f >> c;
    while (!f.eof()) 
    {
        if (c>='a'&&c<='z') data[(int) c - 61][0]++;
        f >> c;
    }
    f.close();
}

int ClearData(int data [62][2]) 
{
    int n=0;
    for (int i=0; i<62; i++) 
    {
        if (data[i][0])
        {
            data[n][0]=data[i][0];
            data[n][1]=data[i][1];
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

void Swap(int data [62][2],int i) 
{
    int x,y;
    x=data[i][0];
    y=data[i][1];
    data[i][0]=data[i+1][0];
    data[i][1]=data[i+1][1];
    data[i+1][0]=x;
    data[i+1][1]=y;
}

void DataSort(int data [62][2], int argc, char* argv[], int i) //Функция которая сортирует все в алфавитном порядке.
{
    char data[i];
    int tmp, j, n;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%s", &data[i]);
        qsort(a,n,sizeof(char[2]), (int (*)(const void *, const void *)) strcmp);
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            printf("%s\n", data[i]);

    } while (n);
}

void WriteData(int data [62][2],int n) //функция, которая записывает данные в другой файл
{
    ofstream f;
    f.open("f1.txt");
    for (int i=n; i>0; i--)
        f << '"' << (char) data[i][1] << '"' << " количество в тексте " << data[i][0] << " reizes!" << endl;
    if (62-n)
        f << 62-n << " " << endl;
    f.close();
}

int main()
{
    int data [62][2];
    CreateArray(data);
    ReadData(data);
    int n = ClearData(data);
    DataSort(data,n);
    WriteData(data,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем в си++ использовать qsort вместо нормальной sort?

Comment: Что за белиберда написана?  Зачем в функции `DataSort` объявлены некие параметры `int argc, char* argv[]`??? Что такое  `a` в `qsort(a,n...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы хранить в массиве количество каждой английской буквы, без учета регистра, нужен массив  всего из `26` элементов. Для буквы `а` инкрементируем первый, для `b` - второй и т.д. Таким образом, ваша программа может выглядеть:

```
// открытие файла
//...
char c;
const size_t count = 26; // количество букв без учета регистра
int m[count] = {0};
while (f >> c) {
    if (isalpha(c)) {   // если это буква
        if ( c <= 'Z')
            c = tolower(c);
        ++m[c - 'a'];     // инкремент соответствующего элемента
    }
}
// теперь каждый элемент массива описывает количество букв
//открываем файл и записываем     
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    if (m[i])
        f1 << char('a' + i) << " : количество и тексте " << m[i] << '\n';
}
```

Если вы хотите эту маленькую программу разделять на функции, то оставлю вам это в качестве  самостоятельной работы...